# Last row of listview only generating pdf itext

Tags: android, listview, pdf, itext

I have a Listview which have button for viewing respective pdf. The pdf generation was done through itext.The problem is the last row of listview has only pdf generating in it.If we click the first row,the pdf showing would be the last row of listview. All pdf are not generating respectivelty.Only the last row is generating pdf.
Please help me.

Comment: Can you provide us the code?, thx

Answer (score 1):

This is because the listview will reuse current view and the itext only get the last current view.
Instead, you should query every view by use getAdapter() get the ListAdapter, and query every item for print:

```
    ListAdapter adapter = listview.getAdapter()
    for (int i=0;i<adapter.getCount();i++)
    {
     View convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,null); //Should some as your current list view layout
     View view = adapter.getView(i,convertView,listview)
       .........
       //working on each view
    }
```